# Esconder y luego mostrar Menú de Navegación

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Ahorita lo que tengo estructurado en mi página Web:

1. Tengo un Banner de presentación(spectrel) que se muestra un texto de bienvenida, abajo de aquel mensaje tengo un botón que hace desaparecer el mensaje. Lo que quisiera hacer es cuando presione el botón desaparezca el mensaje de bienvenida y que me muestre el menú de navegación.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías dar la propiedad `display:none;` al menú de navegación y `display:block;` (aunque esta está por defecto por lo que no tendrías que añadirla manualmente) al mensaje de bienvenida con css, y con js crear una función que cambie estas propiedades a la inversa y esa función asignársela al botón, aquí tienes un ejemplo de lo que te he dicho:

```js
function ocultar(){
  document.getElementById("mensaje").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
* {margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
.mensaje {background:blue;width:100%;height:100px;padding:10px;}
.mensaje p {padding:10px;}
.mensaje input {margin:10px;}
.menu {display:none;width:100%;background:red;height:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <h1>Menu de navegacion.</h1>
</div>
<div class="mensaje" id="mensaje">
  <p>Bienvenido a nuestra web.</p>
  <input type="button" value="Ocultar" id="btn" onclick="ocultar()">
</div>
```